# Excell formula to find number 3 in column ah, then display the text from the same row in column A

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula

I have a large spreadsheet with approximately 20 columns and 100 rows.  Each column has data from a competition, some rows are text, some are numbers that using a formula to rank 1 - 100.

I have another column A on page 2, for trophy lists. So I need a formula that will:

1. On page 2, I want to put 3rd place in Column A Row 1. I need column B1 to search on page 1 column AH to find 3rd place in the rank and reflect the text from that row in column A on page 1.

I know this is confusing, and I can attach a picture of the worksheet if needed.

I'm not very excel savy, but ive made it this far with the sheet and have hit a wall.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Attach the picture, it's always best to include as much info as possibly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the number 3 in cell A1 on Sheet2, the following will display the value of column A in the row that has rank 3 in Sheet1

This can be copied down in Sheet2 if you have other numbers in the rows below

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:AH,MATCH($A1,Sheet1!$AH:$AH,0),1)
```

Comment: Snap! I'm recommending this one cos you got the cell reference A1 in MATCH function whereas I just used the number 3.......

Comment: Yeah but your index formula was more concise so we'll call it a draw!

Comment: This worked! Thank you both so much, i cant tell you how much you have helped me!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need `INDEX/MATCH` like this

`=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(3,Sheet1!AH:AH,0))`

The `MATCH` function finds the position of 3 in column `AH` and then the `INDEX` function returns the value from column `A` in the same row.

Is that what you need?